# How do you 'outsmart 200 spiders' in Cut the Rope?

Tags: achievements, ios, cut-the-rope

In Cut the Rope on iPhone, I have most of the achievements, except for "Spider Tamer" (outsmart 200 spiders) and "Calorie Minimiser" (lose candy 200 times). But I'm sure I should have both. I do have the lesser achievements (outsmart 40 spiders and lose candy 50 times).

So I want to know exactly what constitutes outsmarting a spider? Is it just cutting a rope that the spider is on? Or do you need to successfully complete the level each time, or something else? And do the achievements need to be on multiple levels or only one? I've been playing 3-11 repeatedly just cutting the spider's ropes but no awards yet :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two achievements you're asking about were added in the game's 1.1 update. However, there is a bug with them: if you had already met the requirements for the achievements before you updated, there is no way for you to receive them. This is because you'll never "reach" the 200/400/etc point where the game should give you the achievement, since you were already past that point.

So unfortunately, there's no way for you to get them unless the developer releases a fix.

Comment: outsmartedSpiders >= 200 instead of outsmartedSpiders == 200 should fix the issue.

Hey Dev's?!

Comment: Thanks, that must be it. I'll stop wasting my time now :) IIRC you can reset the game so that's an option for a rainy day.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a bug?

http://twitter.com/#!/jerrodh/status/10209964500975616

Answer (score -1):

Easy 
Just go on a level with spiders
when the spider crawls up the rope *cut the rope* (that is what its a called)
That counts as one keep doing that till you get it 
I just got cause im quite bad at cut the rope an restart level a lot of times